# Why do I keep getting a peer dependancy error even though I have added peer dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json

I am trying to install mocha, enzyme and chai. in order to write tests for my react app. I am using react 17..

However, I keep getting this peer dependency error.(I am new to the frontend world)

```
pm WARN build-info-service-frontend@ requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN build-info-service-frontend@ requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @restart/hooks@0.3.25 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@7.0.0-beta.34 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.34 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN create-react-context@0.3.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-popper@1.3.7 requires a peer of react@0.14.x || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN chai-enzyme@1.0.0-beta.1 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN chai-enzyme@1.0.0-beta.1 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Even though I have added the peer dependencies to my package.json. Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "build-info-service-frontend",
  "homepage": "./",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.disneystreaming.build-info-service-frontend",
    "productName": "Build Info Service Frontend",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2020 Disney Streaming Services"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "install-peerdeps": "^2.0.3",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-table": "^7.6.2",
    "reactstrap": "^8.7.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test:unit": "mocha --require @babel/register --require ignore-styles 'test/**/*.spec.js'",
    "test:unit:watch": "npm run test:unit -- --watch",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/register": "^7.12.10",
    "babel-preset-react-app-babel-7": "^4.0.2-0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-enzyme": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1",
    "jsdom": "^16.4.0",
    "mocha": "^8.2.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0",
    "cheerio": "0.19.x || 0.20.x || 0.22.x || ^1.0.0-0",
    "enzyme": "^2.7.0 || ^3.0.0",
    "react": "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0"
  }
}
```

Any idea what I can do to solve this ? I am not sure what else I can do to solve the issue.. Any hep would be much appreciated

Comment: version mismatch: eg react-popper@1.3.7 requires a peer of react@0.14.x || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0, but you have react@17.0.1

Comment: btw don't add anything in `peerDependencies`, libraries (like react-popper) add `peerDependencies` in their package.json. You need to install packages by adding them to your  `dependencies` or `devDependencies`.

Comment: also most of the times you can safely ignore these warnings

Comment: no, as I said `peerDependencies` is for libraries, so that they can tell you what dependencies you need to install manually

Comment: nope. Add them to your dependencies or devDependencies

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Ohhh okay I see what you mean now.. so essentially if I want to use react-popper I would need to use the older version of react for my whole project ? and adding it as a peer dependancy wouldn't work ?

Comment: It's just a warning, newer react should work fine too. If it's not working then use old react.